# Authorization and Authentication for Azure AD in .netcore app

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am working on a .netcore 2.1 api application which tried to access the Graph api using the On Behalf Of Flow.

I have a general understanding of the below code, like it is used for on behalf of user authentication.
But can someone explain to be what it means line by line or any documentation that would help me to understand this and other options for authorization and authentication?

```cs
    services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("default"));
            });
            services.AddAuthorization(o =>
            {
                o.AddPolicy("default", builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .RequireClaim(AzureAdClaimTypes.Scope, 
    "user_impersonation");
                });
            });

            services
                .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(o =>
                {
                    AuthenticationOptions authSettings = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Get<AuthenticationOptions>();

                    o.Authority = authSettings.Authority;

                    o.SaveToken = true;

                    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudiences = new List<string> { authSettings.ClientId, authSettings.AppIdUri }
                    };
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
services.AddMvc(o =>
{
        o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("default"));
});
```

Adds a global filter that applies to all MVC controllers and actions. 
In this case it requires authorisation with the "default" policy.

```
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
     o.AddPolicy("default", builder =>
     {
            builder
                  .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                  .RequireClaim(AzureAdClaimTypes.Scope, 
    "user_impersonation");
     });
});
```

Defines the "default" authorisation policy. 
Requires authentication succeeds and that the caller has the default user_impersonation scope. 
This scope/delegated permission thus needs to be required and granted to the calling app. 
It is very important to check for the presence of delegated/application permissions. 
And this does that, though it won't work if you have more than 1 delegated permission defined + granted because the claim will contain all of them in one string. 
You can use a claims transformation to split them if needed though.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

Adds authentication services and defines JWT authentication as default.

```
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
           AuthenticationOptions authSettings = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Get<AuthenticationOptions>();
```

Adds JWT authentication scheme services and gets config object.

```
o.Authority = authSettings.Authority;
```

Sets the authority. This URL is used to fetch the identity provider metadata JSON document at app start.
That document then has e.g. the valid issuer URI and signing keys. 
So basically it's used to load token validation data.

```
o.SaveToken = true;
```

Save access tokens received to the request so they can be accessed from wherever you need them during the request. 
You need this with OBO because you need to send this token received along with other data to get another token.

```
o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
      ValidAudiences = new List<string> { authSettings.ClientId, authSettings.AppIdUri }
};
```

Defines that this API accepts two different audiences.
This is a good practice with AAD. 
I've seen tokens sometimes with the client id in the aud claim, and sometimes it's the app ID URI. 
So it's better to allow both. 
But defining these also means the API will not accept tokens meant for another API, which is good.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Juunas

Comment: do you have any idea regarding the below question,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958336/refresh-id-token-before-it-expires-in-aspnet-core-mvc