# Refresh id token before it expires in aspnet core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am working on a aspnet core MVC project which calls an API which is secured by OAuth2.0.

I was able to access the API and get the response properly with the code below,

**Startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["AzureAD:Instance"] + 
                 "/" + Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"];
                options.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"];
                options.Secret = Configuration["AzureAD:Secret"];
                options.Callback = Configuration["AzureAD:Callback"];
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });

        services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "sign-in",
                template: "signin-oidc")};


            ...

    });
    }
```

**Controller.cs**

I am getting the token from the HttpContext.

But the token expires after few hours. Is there a way to refresh the id token before it expires.
I tried few examples in stack overflow. But none worked for me.

Is there a way to get this to work without using the IdentityModel used in example below?
https://github.com/mderriey/aspnet-core-token-renewal/blob/master/src/MvcClient/Startup.cs

Comment: This might help: https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to refresh id token .  Id token contains information about an End-User , once your client app get id token from OpenID provider , it will validate the token , decode the token and sign in user using cookie authentication . The user information is serialized and stored in application cookie which will send on each next request from browser to keep user's basic profile information and authentication status .

By default ,the cookie is created with a session-based lifetime - that is, until the browser/tab is closed . So id token will be used at the first time and then cookie authentication take over .

Usually what we consider is how to refresh the access token . Access token allows access to certain defined server resources , we can use refresh token to renew access token after it expires .

The article your provides is showing how to refresh access token , and  aligns the lifetime of the ASP.NET session cookie with OIDC access token(control the cookie's lifetime ). That is not much related to your scenario .

Comment: But I have seen that the id_token/cookie expires after sometime(probably an hour), after that when I try to access the API I get "UnAuthorised". So what is the best way to authenticate a user when the cookie expires with id_token(as id_token is used in the API)?

Comment: No , normally access token is used for API .

Comment: If cookie expires , just redirect user to OIDC authentication  schema for sign in

Comment: Thanks Nan, I am new to all this so does not have a great understanding. Is it a general rule that API should use the access token and not id token? So should there be a seperate app registration for the UI and the API in the Azure portal? At the moment it uses the same registration. Under the app registration> Authentication>Advanced settings> ID Token is checked, I thought that is the reason for the API to use only ID token.

Comment: it's better to register your app and api as different apps , access token includes permission/role claims , is used to access the web api : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

Comment: Thanks Nan, I will try the access token method.

Comment: Hi Nan, after lots of googling and trying out a few methods to create the access_token I could not get the code to output the access token. All I get is the authorization code. So I have raised another stack overflow question for it. Could you please have a look at what I am missing,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030348/convert-authorization-code-to-access-token-in-asp-net-mvc-to-call-a-net-framewo

Comment: OK , i will look into that .