# Convert authorization code to access_token in ASP.NET Core MVC to call a .NET framework API

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application which calls a .NET framework API.

The MVC application uses the hybrid flow and gets the `id_token` and authorization code using the following code in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration["AzureAD:Instance"] + 
             "/" + Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"];
            options.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"];
            options.Secret = Configuration["AzureAD:Secret"];
            options.Callback = Configuration["AzureAD:Callback"];
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
        });

    services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "sign-in",
            template: "signin-oidc")};


        ...

});
```

In the controller, when I check the `HttpContext`, I can get the `id_token` and authorization code. But I need to pass the `access_token` to the API.

How do I get the `access_token` from the authorization code?

Is MSAL/ADAL used for the above purpose? If so how can I get the `access_token` using MSAL?

Could someone please point me to some example code?

Comment: Do click on "Mark as Answer" on the post, this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ITokenAcquisition` service. Add a constructor to your Controller, making the ITokenAcquisition service available (used by the ASP.NET dependency injection mechanism)

For example,

```
public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
{
  this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
}
private ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition;
```

Then you can get the access token like this

```
 var accessToken =
 await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(HttpContext, 
                                                  new[] {Constants.ScopeUserRead});
```

You can refer to this [complete sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph) for more details.

Comment: All the samples mentioned here shows to access token in controller. Is there any way to get access_token in Startup.cs and make call to Api from there? Any link or sample is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct , ADAL/MSAL are used to acquire tokens in order to call secured Web APIs. If using OpenID connect middleware , in `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event , you can use ADAL/MSAL to acquire access token with authorization code .

If using Azure AD v1.0 , you could refer to [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) which use ADAL to acquire access token . Check the [`OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L66). [Here](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1) is another article with code sample .

If using Azure AD v2.0 (to sign-in users with Work and School accounts and Microsoft Personal accounts) , you can refer to below link for code samples which use MSAL :

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2

Your scenario matches the forth code sample : `4-WebApp-your-API` .

That codes sample use `Microsoft.Identity.Web` library which make it easier to build your Web Apps on top of Microsoft identity platform for developers , add your api as scope :

```
services.AddAzureAdV2Authentication(Configuration)
        .AddMsal(new string[] { Configuration["TodoList:TodoListScope"] })
```

And get token like :

```
var accessToken = await this._tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(this._contextAccessor.HttpContext, new[] { this._TodoListScope });
```

Comment: It is working with the inmemorycache(not for insession which I would prefer). But I was reading through and was thinking is it best to save the token in a cache, wouldn't it be better to store it in a cookie. The above example uses cookie authentication, and I can get the authorization code, so all I realy want is to convert it into access_token and refresh it using refresh_token. Is there a different way to get it? Or what is the advantage of using the inmemory caching(because I have to add this cahing in API as well according to the above code, is it a good idea as API's should be stateless)

Comment: it's up to you , you can store the token in where you want to store , in memory , database ,cookie ...

Comment: do you know any sample code for cookie authentication,msal to create access_token?

Comment: Check https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph